# AWS Lambda function returns error from API Gateway, but not when invoked directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple Lambda function which writes items to a DynamoDB table. 
username is partition key, createDateTime is sort key.

Invoking this function from Lambda itself successfully inserts items into the table. However when called through API Gateway, I'm receiving the following error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error putting order into dynamodb: MultipleValidationErrors: There were 14 validation errors:\n* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Item['createDateTime'] to be a structure\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '2' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '3' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '4' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '5' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '6' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '7' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '8' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '9' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '10' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '11' found in params.Item['createDateTime']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '12' found in params.Item['createDateTime']"
}
```

I fail to understand why my code works when invoked locally, but not when invoked through API Gateway? Code below:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var DOC = require("dynamodb-doc");

AWS.config.update({region: "eu-west-1"});
var dynamodb = new DOC.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    var tableName = "MarketOrder";

    if (event.http_method == 'POST') {
        var datetime = new Date().getTime().toString();

        dynamodb.putItem({
            "TableName": tableName,
            "Item" : { 
                "username"   : event.username,
                "createDateTime" : datetime,
                "orderType": event.orderType,
                "numberOfShares": event.numberOfShares,
                "price": event.price,
                "validToDate": event.validToDate
            }
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("dynamodb error: " + err);
                context.done('Error putting order into dynamodb: ' +err);
            }
            else {
                console.log('great success: '+JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
                context.succeed('Sucessfully saved market order');
            }
        });
    } 
    ....
    } else {
        context.fail('Invalid operation specified:' + event.http_method);
    }
};
```

Comment: "I fail to understand why my code works when invoked locally, but not when invoked through API Gateway?" It seems obvious that the event data being passed by API Gateway is different from what you have been testing with directly.  I see you are logging the event object in the first line of your function. Try comparing the logs from direct invocation vs API Gateway invocation and you should see what the issue is. You will probably need to modify your API Gateway mapping template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is an issue in your mapping template. I would suggest to turn on CloudWatch logging for your API to troubleshoot.

See https://rpgreen.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/easy-api-gatewaylambda-serverless-api-loggingdebugging/

Comment: Thanks, mapping was the issue. So the actual issue is solved. However it would be nice to get that tool you linked to working as well, btu I'm getting "ClientError: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the FilterLogEvents operation: The specified log group does not exist." when calling with python -m apilogs.bin get --api-id <api-id-here> --stage prod --watch. Any pointers?

Comment: You will need to ensure that logging is enabled for your API. I've just updated the tool to produce a better error message and link to the docs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-stage-settings.html

Comment: Logging is enabled, I can see the actual logs in CloudWatch. The log group is named "API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_<id>/<stage>". Perhaps I missunderstand what to put after --api-id ?

Comment: I think a found the explanation as to why it is not working, however I don't understand why this is happening. If I go through the console to CloudWatch and look at logs, all my log groups are visible. I have several for my lambda functions, and a couple for my API gateways. However when I run "aws logs describe-log-groups", only the lambda log groups are returned. This explains why the call from apilogs is failing. Like I said, no idea why API gateway log groups are not returned...

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar experience and learned the following:  when testing the Lambda function independently (using the AWS Lambda console's built-in 'Test' feature), the Event parameter was an *object*; when using the built-in API Gateway test feature, Event was a *string*.  I learned this by comparing the CloudWatch logs for the 2 different scenarios and noticing that, while the inputs looked similar in both cases, all line-break characters used to make a well-formed JSON resulted in '\n' characters in the Event string, which my Lambda function (written in Node.js, using JSON.parse()) couldn't interpret.  So I added the following code to bulletproof my function and it seems to work well (note here my code is inspecting the 'body' object inside of Event, but could be used on the entire Event object if needed):

```
  var body;

  switch(typeof(event.body)) {
    case "string":
      //strips all-types of linebreak and carriage return characters from the event.body string
      var str = event.body.replace(/[\r\n]+/gm,"");
      body = JSON.parse(str);
      break;
    case "object":
      body = event.body;
      break;
    default:
      throw("invalid input for event.body");
  }
```